# Как обрезать canvas сверху?

Tags: canvas

Есть объект canvas. 
Как обрезать весь верх на 200px?

То есть переместиться вниз на 200px от верха картинки и сохранить всё что ниже находится. А верхную часть удалить.

Comment: Переместиться или просто скрыть верхние 200px?

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: `ctx.getImageData(0,200, canvas.width, canvas.height-200)`

Comment: @manking А css стили уже не канают?

Comment: @manking, п.с. если Ваше сообщение в комментариях адресовано конкретному юзеру - пишите его ник, а перед ним "собачку"

Comment: @VladKosko, если изменить размеры холста, то по идее, весь холст будет очищен

Comment: @Дмытрык сори забыл как тут всё устроено

Comment: @VladKosko, это я не Вам. В сообщениях адресованых вопрошающему ник можно не указывать

Comment: @Дмытрык можно не размеры менять а чем то "накрыть canvas" сверху, будет производительнее думаю...

Comment: @VladKosko, это чисто косметическ - canvas с изображением никуда не денется. Типа замести пыль под ковер

Comment: @Дмытрык а оно и не описано что конкретно надо. Мне кажеться кто то хочет рекламу просто скрыть или что то на подобии.